# ¿Por qué no puedo ver el contenido de la carpeta en git hub?

Tags: git, github

Cree el repositorio en `<ubicación por definir>` y subi mi proyecto que contiene dos carpetas, una de **frontend** (donde estan todos los archivos de Angular) y **server** (aca esta todo lo referido a node, express etc..).

Pero desde git hub Solo me permite ver el contenido de la carpeta "server", no puedo ver el contenido de la carpeta "frontend".

Hice todo lo correspondiente desde local:

```
git init, 
git add . 
git commit -m 'aca mi commit'
git remote add origin http://urlDelRepositorioRemotoGitHub
```

y como último `git push -u origin master`.

Aca les dejo la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi tengo las carpetas en local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dentro de la carpeta frontend

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sospecho que la carpeta `frontend` sea a su vez otro repositorio git. Puedes comprobarlo entrando en ella (localmente) y haciendo `ls -la` y si te aparece una carpeta oculta llamada `.git` es que es otro repositorio. En ese caso pon (estando dentro de ella) el comando `git remote -v` para ver la URL a la que apunta ese otro repositorio. O eso, o es un enlace simbólico a una carpeta que está fuera del repositorio

Comment: gracias @abulafia! al hacer ls -la sobre la carpeta frontend aparece una carpeta .git/ (resaltada en color violeta). al hacer git remote -v no me muestra ninguna url.

Comment: Qué curioso... ¿y si dentro de esa carpeta haces `git log`? Te salen commits? Si no te sale ninguno lo más sencillo sería que eliminaras la carpeta `frontend/.git` con todo su contenido, y luego simplemente hicieras `git add frontend` para añadir el contenido de esa carpeta al repositorio principal (y luego `git push` por supuesto)

Comment: al hacer git log, solo muestra initial commit

Comment: Pues entonces esa carpeta `frontend/.git` no vale para nada. Fuera con ella :-)

Comment: borro el repositorio remoto y creo uno nuevo? porque la carpeta frontend tiene archivos

Comment: No. Basta que borres la carpeta .`git` que hay en frontend y  luego añadas los archivos de la carpeta frontend al repositorio "principal" (con `git add`, normalmente). Luego `git push` al repositorio remoto que ya tenías, y el problema debería quedar resuelto.

Comment: es raro todo esto, estoy mirando las carpetas que hay dentro de frontend y no hay ninguna carpeta con el nombre .git

Comment: Ah, pero es lo que te había preguntado al principio. Que si había una carpeta llamada .`git` dentro de frontend. Me dijiste que sí... entonces lo que querías decir es que había una _al mismo nivel_ que la de frontend, y no dentro de ella? Esa no hay que borrarla, esa es el repositorio "principal". Si no hay carpeta .`git` dentro de frontend mi primera hipótesis queda invalidada. Quizás entonces la segunda. Un `ls -la` desde la carpeta "principal" ¿cómo muestra la carpeta `frontend`? ¿Como un enlace simbólico?

Comment: acabo de editar mi publicación subiendo 2 imagenes de como tengo las carpetas y lo que hay en la carpeta frontend

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113836/discussion-between-abulafia-and-claudio).

Answer (score 1):

Tuve que configurar la opcion de windows para que me muestre archivos ocultos, Después entre a mi proyecto y ví que tenia una carpeta `.git` (esa no hay que borrar) en el mismo nivel que las carpetas frontend y server. Pero dentro de la carpeta **frontend** tenia otra carpeta `.git` oculta tmb (esta si la borre).No se que hice para que cree esa carpeta en frontend pero bueno... Entonces aparentemente por esa razon al tener la carpeta .git dentro de la carpeta frontend, git hub interpreta que la carpeta frontend pertenece a otro repositorio o a otro proyecto, impidiendo ver el contenido.
Asi que despues de borrarla es cuestion de volver a hacer los comandos

**git add .**

**git commit -m 'mi commit'**

**git push**

y listo, con esto debería funcionar.

En mi caso por accidente borre la carpeta .git que estaba en el mismo nivel que las carpetas frontend y server. Asi que desde git hub, borre el repositorio remoto y volví a crear todo de nuevo.